# Can elastic search long document?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a study project about identify text content must use JS. Input is a paragraph includes at least 15 lines and search in 100 text files from 3 to 5 pages. Output is which text file has the same content as the input text.
Can Elastic resolve it? Or can you recommend me some solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I found a blog entry from https://web.archive.org/web/20210510013958/https://ambar.cloud/blog/2017/01/02/es-large-text/ (link died since the original post, so using Wayback Machine to access it) that can respond to your question. There is an in depth example similar to yours.

ElasticSearch can deal with with large documents and still deliver quite a performance, but for cases like yours its important to set up the index correctly. 
Lets supose you have ElasticSearch documents with a text field with 3 to 5 pages worth of text. 
When you try to query documents that contain a paragraph in the large text field, ElasticSearch will perform a search through all the terms from all the documents and their fields, including the large text field. 
During merge ElasticSearch collects all the found documents into memory, including the large text field. After building the results into memory, ElasticSearch will try to send these large documents as a single JSON response. This is very exprensive in terms of performance.
ElasticSearch should handle the large text field separately from other fields. To do this, in the index mapping you should set the parameter `store:true` for the large text field. This tells ElasticSearch to store the field separately from other document's fields. You should also exclude the large text field from `_source` by adding this parameter in the index settings:

```
_source: {
    excludes: [
        "your_large_text_field"
    ]
}
```

If you set your indexes this way, the large text field will be separated from `_source`. Querying the large text field is now much more effective since it is stored separately and there is no need to merge it with `_source`.

To conclude, yes, ElasticSearch can handle the search of large text fields, and, with some extra settings it can increase the search performance by [1100 times](https://web.archive.org/web/20211215155858/https://ambar.cloud/blog/2017/01/02/es-large-text/#side-effects).

Comment: The link is dead :(